# is it possible to use bitwise operations on arrays(a long piece of memory)

Tags: c++

There are two arrays as follows

```
int a[100]={1,1,...}
int b[100]={2,5,...}
```

Is there any way to operate them like this

```
c=a|b
```

the result of `c` is

```
{3,5,...}
```

I want to operate memory directly like memcpy

I don't want to use loop

Comment: `c=a&b` - It will make `and` of their addresses

Comment: You can't do `c=a&b` but you can do what you want with a function/algorithm.

Comment: As-is, you'd have to loop through the individual array elements and apply the operation.

Comment: `std::transform(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(b), std::begin(c), [](int i1, int i2) { return i1 & i2; });`.

Comment: You're going to have to have a loop at some point as you need to visit each n byte section and bitwise and them together.

Comment: You mean `|`, not `&`.

Comment: If the size is fixed you can unroll the loop. You can also cheat using recursion instead of iteration. However a loop will be the best solution. Also your example of memcpy is not good. On some level there is a loop with memcpy.

Comment: careful man!@AndyG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bitwise operations works by moving elements of the operation into registers and then doing the operation on registers. That means you are limited to the size of registers for your operations which is hardware dependent but at best is 64 bit (or 128 bit in some new hardware cases). This means even with some trickery, you would be able to do 2 bitwise operations at the same time. If speed is your concern, I would suggest using parallel for achieving your result. I also have to mention that your example creates the arrays on the stack witch limits the size of your array , which means you won't be able to see noticeable speed changes.

Comment: Depending on the CPU SIMD instructions may offer more that 128 bits.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks for the info. Still he is limited to the size of registers and can do 4 integers at a time. He still has to loop thru the array.

Comment: I agree with that.

Comment: thank you!   speed is my concern.  You answered my question perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your own array type in c++ and overload the `operator&()` function:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
class MyArray {
    template<typename X, size_t M>
    friend MyArray<X,M> operator&(const MyArray<X,M>& a, MyArray<X,M>& b) {
         MyArray<X,M> c;
         for(size_t i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
             c.array_[i] = a.array_[i] & b.array_[i];
         }
     }
     std::array<T,N> array_;
 public:
     MyArray() {
     }
     MyArray(std::initializer_list l) array_(l) {
     }
     // ...
};
```

And use that like

```
MyArray<int,100> a { 1,1, /* ... */ };
MyArray<int,100> b { 2,5, /* ... */ };

MyArray<int,100> c = a&b;
```

---

It's also possible to overload that `operator&()` function for `std::array` directly (probably easiest way as @Jarod proposed):

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
std::array<T,N> operator&(const std::array<T,N>& a, std::array<T,N>& b) {
    std::array<T,N> c;
    std::transform(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(b), std::begin(c), [](T i1, T i2) { return i1 & i2; });
    return c;
}
```

Comment: and, there is a loop.

Comment: @Amadeus You well know that's not possible without one. Though it's hidden from the client.

Comment: Just showing that a loop must exists somewhere. By the way @jarod42 comments is easier

Comment: @Amadeus Jarod's comment also implies a loop. I just wanted to show the OP that it's possible to overload operator functions.

Comment: Thank you! Now i know that it is impossible to do that without loop